# Narrow type of object property based on key name

Tags: typescript, narrowing

Given the following function that iterates over an object's properties:

```js
function iterate<O extends Record<string, unknown>>(o: O, cb: (key: keyof O, value: O[keyof O], obj: O) => void) {
  for (const key in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      cb(key, o[key], o);
    }
  }
}
```

In the following code, indexing into the object narrows its type, but checking the key name does not:

```js
iterate({
  name: "Sally",
  age: 30,
}, (key, value, obj) => { // key: "name" | "age"; value: string | number
  if (key === "name") {
    const indexedValue = obj[key]; //  indexedValue: string;
    console.log(value.toUpperCase(), indexedValue.toUpperCase());
  } else {
    const indexedValue = obj[key]; // indexedValue: number;
    console.log(value.toFixed(), indexedValue.toFixed());
  }
});
```

As a result, `value.toUpperCase()` is an error because `value` might not be a string, but `indexedValue.toUpperCase()` works because it's been narrowed. Similarly, `value.toFixed()` is an error because `value` might not be a number, but `indexedValue.toFixed()` works because it's been narrowed.

Is there a way to specify the type of `iterate` so that a conditional comparison of `key` inside the callback can narrow `value`? If not, why does indexing narrow the type while checking the key does not? They seem equivalent, but I wouldn't be surprised if there are cases I'm not thinking of where the two are not equivalent and hence the key comparison would not be safe as a way to narrow the value.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDKBTATgQzQHgPKKoAeaYAJgM6IBKqEc6ZOFU6MYA5gDSLgDWYOAHcwAPlEAKOAC5EeHhABGsiX1QBPWWvVxgcngDdMAGxCpZeANrbdcgLo84igFYWAlIgC8oxAbgwyDwBvAChERGAGRAl6MBZEbWQkOGCw8OQ9KQA6AAtMCjwRAAV0OAAHDCh1VQ03VPT0pRr1R2sNB0QUgG408IBfNIGBkJQMbFQJUPCwTABbc0QAIgBlE2N1Ra40zA4FgGYABi2+nmbDEzNHFw9vRCmM6MTPZ6WZ+cX6xoR49jJiVDIADULqgvJ0XG11HYeg1YhQ4MZUFljHAOBIjKYkVA4ABVMoVdAAYXyEzcPF+-yBIKy2LxBOJFFJbhhiD6hGMjLuvUQcKgST+RABwMxYKczkh0O5cIRSJRaIxZhpcAAYjBBWQJGT+ZThYrsar1ZrmYMQn1mUA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to establish a relationship between `key` and `value`. As it currently stands, TS can't prove that `"name"` will not be paired with a `number`.

The way you can do this is by generating a discriminated union of tuples. For the given example this would be `["name", string] | ["age", number]`. Then use this as parameters for the callback. In recent version TypeScript (since 4.6 [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/46266)) can follow that variables destructured from a discriminated unions have a relationship between them and narrow `value` when you narrow `key`.

We ca do this using a mapped type to generate the tuple for each key in the type and then index into the mapped type to get the union of tuples.

```
type KeyValueEntries<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: [key: P, value: T[P], obj: T]
}[keyof T]

function iterate<O extends Record<string, unknown>>(o: O, cb: (...a:KeyValueEntries<O>) => void) {
  for (const key in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      cb(key, o[key], o);
    }
  }
}

iterate({
  name: "Sally",
  age: 30,
}, (key, value, obj) => {
  if (key === "name") {
    const indexedValue = obj[key];
    console.log(value.toUpperCase(), indexedValue.toUpperCase());
  } else {
    const indexedValue = obj[key];
    console.log(value.toFixed(), indexedValue.toFixed());
  }
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIDUCGAbArhAogO2AJwEsIBnAHgBUA+KAXigG8AoKKAbQAUoDsoBreAPYAzKOQC6ALjb8QU9gBooAN1QYp5DmMUCARgCt1YxgF9WM4aKOMhabAGNgBATwLAIeJG9IB5KBAAebtgAJsRQAEoQdgJ4waTE+NwA5oq2vNgCAO7YlJQAFAJS3op2OlJ5AHRVSBJwiKpYuIQkPpQAlLTUSgIEwR1MLEIxUHnR2Al88Fw8Av3MLFwiBRUAFkjE3tnseAKQeKB5Mm1zCwulh-DaZvBaULMA3PMsxvMvL4yu7p4QeQNQ2EgALYQKQAIgAyqgUCBQfJ5kgkiCoABmAAMcOMiguIEUKnQEG0+g6NGofwISxktBodFBAOBoJOZ2cE24wQCEGCyHxtDu+muIDEj1OY2IAhQEAqKAESTyeIwFWAAgAqmA9gBhdY-NqKVnszkNBXK1XuDXELVtIVQYx+FBmhhPKAi4DTNn+DlcjA83R6fmCh0isUSqUyuUSxUAMQIbuCeW1Lr1HrDAkj0djFteJgtQA)

Comment: Thank you! Follow up question, if you don't mind. In your construction, the callback must accept all three arguments. Is there way to type this so that the callback can only specify as many arguments as it will actually use? See https://tsplay.dev/W4nXAN for an example where `obj` is omitted from the callback which results in a type error. I'd like it to be possible for the callback to take only `key` and `value`, or only `key`, or no arguments at all, if it wants to.

Comment: I found that I could make each argument optional by using a separate mapped type for each argument count and function overloads: https://tsplay.dev/N5zO9m Interestingly, the order of the overloads seems to be important. If I order the overloads with the single argument version coming first and, the two argument version second, and the three argument version third, it results in type errors. I'm still curious if there's a more elegant way that doesn't involve multiple mapped types and/or overloads.

Comment: I can use a single type with a second generic argument to determine the count of elements in the tuple: https://tsplay.dev/ND2DOW but this still seems a bit messy, and I'm still curious about the order of overloads and why they matter.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information in the callback method to say that value is the type of obj[key].

Suppose that TypeScript picked up that `obj[key]` and `value` had the same type here. This casting allows us to imagine TypeScript was doing so:

```
if (key === "name") {
    const indexedValue = obj[key];
    console.log((value as string).toUpperCase(), indexedValue.toUpperCase());
  } else {
    const indexedValue = obj[key];
    console.log((value as number).toFixed(), indexedValue.toFixed());
  }
```

This is problematic - if you did this, and then swapped out iterate for this method, everything would still compile and crash at runtime:

```
function iterate<O extends Record<string, unknown>>(o: O, cb: (key: keyof O, value: O[keyof O], obj: O) => void) {
  const keys: (keyof O)[] = Object.keys(o);
  keys.forEach((key, i) => {
    cb(key, o[keys[(i + 1) % keys.length]], o);
  })
}
```